# Custom UITableCell Nib file not displaying

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nib

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UINib *myNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"cellView" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:myNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
cell.nameLabel.text = @"Name Field";

return cell;
}
```

When I run the app, it shows a blank tableView. I have tried multiple different ways to register the
nib file. The nib is connected to the customViewCell.h/.m files.

Comment: Is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method getting called? Put a log on the first line of that function.

Comment: haha no it wasn't. I fixed it thanks.